# .html() event not working inside other .html() insertion

Tags: jquery

http://portfolio.paulchelmis.com/design/design

Working on a portfolio site, and so far I've been able to figure out every one of my numerous kinks by searching etc, until now. Anyway, click the first or second link in the righthand grid.  My issue is about jquery's `.html()` method — I have it set so that when one of those info cards `.thumbinfo` are clicked, the html inside of `#detailtext` and `#detailimages` is inserted using aforementioned method.

That works fine — but inside of the `#detailtext` `div` I have the two next and prev buttons (`.btnnext` & `.btnlast`) for changing 'pages' without closing out first. The problem is I can't seem to get those buttons to fire at all unless they're taken out of their parent div. What's more, from what I can tell, those buttons won't fire ANY event, not just the `.html` command.

I wrapped one in a `#clicked` `<a>` tag to make sure it wasn't just a z-index problem or something.

Anyway... is there a fix for this, or should I find a workaround? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

TL;DR: jQuery's .html event, or any event, doesn't seem to be working when fired by an element INSIDE of previously injected html (from the .html() method).

Comment: Hello, it helps if you show code snippits. Also, you should create your issue in jsfiddle rather than posting your website.

Comment: Always attach event handlers using `.on()` when working with dynamically created/injected elements.

Comment: This is most likely an event delegation issue. It looks like you're replacing the next/prev buttons, resulting in their events going \*poof\*. I haven't navigated to your site yet though (and probably wont), you should post the relevant code/html here.

Comment: smerny/Kevin B, I was afraid someone would say that :-) I'll get on that though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With dynamically added elements, you need to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind to an element that already exists within the page.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

For example, to bind the click event to a table row that is added dynamically, you bind to the document (or ideally an element closer in the DOM for better performance):

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This was the hunch that I was getting as well, however it didn't seem to solve the problem. When adding such a line, the function works, including after removing the original .click() binding, but still doesn't change the behavior of the dynamically added buttons. I figure this is because I gave them the same ID as the original trigger, therefore thought (hoped) they'd have the same behavior without having to be rebound.

Comment: If you post your code here, or better yet create a jsFiddle.net example I could probably help you further. One question though, did you say you'd duplicating IDs?

Comment: The previous elements with those ID's get removed when the new ones are created, and vice versa. So, technically not existing at the same time. Would W3C still hate me for that?

Comment: No, not as long as they're removed before the re-insertion.